# Observable creates infinite loop when http request fails

Tags: javascript, angular, http, rxjs, observable

I use Observable in my Angular 4 application to load data from a web api.

Have a service that looks like this:

```
import { Injectable, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class WorkgroupsService {

    constructor(private _http: Http) {

    }

    getWorkgroups() {
        return this._http.get(`/api/security/getsecurityworkgroups`).map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

And use it something like this:

```
loadWorkgroups() {
    this._workgroupsService.getWorkgroups()
        .subscribe((workgroups: any) => {
            this.workgroups = workgroups;
        });
}
```

Whenever the api returns an error it creates an infinite loop, the request is sent over and over again.

How can I stop it?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is certainly somewhere else and not in this example. An `error` notification doesn't cause resubscription.